# Data structure to block when a list of element has reach its quota

Tags: java, rate-limiting

I have a 'key' that let me call a rest endpoint 500 times per minutes (each key can either be 200, 300 or 500)
 when the key has reached its quota within a 1 minute (1 min bucket not sliding window) the endpoint returns a 429 (rate limited) with a waiting delay. Once the delay has passed I can re-used again this key.

My API is a kind of proxy (client call my API, my API calls an other service by providing one of the keys)
My API would stack all my users keys so that in a sense it becomes 1 big key.
and that when 'any' of my client call my api, my system would smartly chose 1 key which still has quota and when that key reached quota it removes it from the available keys list, or queue or whatever structure

I'm having difficulties choosing a good data structure and logic for it. What I have in mind is something like this

1) get a key which has still quota and has at least 1 remaining call available -1a) if no key are available just 'wait' until one becomes available

2) call the endpoint

3) Decrease the key quota of 1 and if the key got rate limited remove it from the 'queue' or 'list' or whatever.

4) back to 1

Note that the endpoint my API is calling returns useful information such as "requestRemaining" that indicate how much request a key has still left before it gets rate limited. "rate delay" that indicates when the key ca be used again in case it gets rate limited.

I think a good solution here would be to pro-actively knowing when a key is going to be come rate limited instead of relying on the endpoint responses only. Like this we avoid making a call 'for nothing' to endpoint with a key that has reached quota.

I have already tried something with DelayQueue and some semaphore to block when no keys are available but I have an issue knowing in advance if a key will become rate limited.
I would like to be concurrent at the 'request' level not at the key level. Meaning that I don't want a client to lock a key until it made the request. If a key has a quota of 500 i would like at max 500 concurrent client to use 1 single key;

I would love to have the input of someone more experienced on how they would approach this.

Comment: Interesting question. I might tried to give a shot later today just for fun without profit

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind blocking on a key you can have a DelayQueue of Keys were the getDelay() would be the time the key is rate limited (0 if the key is still in quota)

```
private void executeRequest(...) {
 long delay = 0L
 try {
  // .take from the queue (it will remove it from the queue)
  // execute your request
  // if you get 429 take the delay from the response header
 } finally {
  //put back the key in the queue but setting the "delay" (0 or whatever the header had
 }

}
```

The fact that you remove the key before using it will avoid anyone else to use that key. in the finally close you always put back the key and thanks to the DelayQeeue that key will only be available by .take() when the delay is reached

*Edit: Sorry just saw you edited your question to have it occurrent on requests rather than keys. In that case... I'm not sure but i'm curious at how other people would approach this as well*